# What PVC pipe can withstand hot water, sunlight and be used for drinking water?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

What type of PVC pipe would be able to do that?

Comment: CPVC does what you want as-far-as temp and drinking.  Not sure about UV exposure.

Comment: Seems that should be an answer (2/3 isn't terrible)

Answer (score 2):

CPVC with a coat of paint on the outside to protect from sunlight. Of course, a non-PVC pipe might suit your actual needs better, depending on your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

PEX would be a good alternative to a 'PVC' product. It also only has a slightly lower working temperature than CPVC (180F compared to 200F respectively). It is rated for potable water. It does not have a great UV resistance, however unless purchasing specialty CPVC or PVC with 1-2% Titanium Dioxide, neither are these products. I believe unless working in copper, PEX, PVC and CPVC should be covered and protected against UV exposure.

Comment: PEX is very had to paint - it falls off. CPVC takes paint without a fight.

Comment: Depending on the application (exterior of my home) I'd always rather see flat contiguous structure. Why paint? Maybe a folded aluminum shield like flashing material?

Comment: If you are running hot water through it you will also want insulation, which in turn solves the paint problem. Now you just need to protect the insulation from birds and rodents.

Comment: The question implied bare pipe exposed to sunlight. You can, of course, build a box around the pipe - but that is not the question.